# iOS 13 errors (WebKit) with Cordova - App Hangs

Tags: ios, cordova, webkit, mobile-webkit

My team is working on a Cordova application, we’ve recently encountered an issue on iOS 13 devices where after a while, the application would freeze and only way to recover is to kill the application.

When the application freezes, we noticed that the following msgs:
•   [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1 – this seems to be unrelated as it appears as soon as the application starts
•   [IPC] Connection::waitForSyncReply – this message seems to only appear once the application freezes

I found in the WebKit source code that this message seems to indicate something is timing out:
https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/e4ea20a88aa7ab0f64d67ffaadaa02fc7a93c49c/Source/WebKit/Platform/IPC/Connection.cpp#L634

Anyone else encounter this type of issue?  Have anymore info?  Any and all input is appreciated!